# Posting Message to Slack via NodeJS Lambda Function - Data Variable Not Rendering

Tags: node.js, lambda, slack-api

I've got an AWS lambda function implemented in Node that posts a message to a Slack channel. I've created a SlackApp, with the incoming webhook feature enabled. I'm sending a message to the hook via https. The lambda calls the following function that formats the message:

```
function slackConvertFromSNSMessage(sns_event) {
    let slack_message;
    let slack_message_text;
    const slack_message_user = 'foo';
    const slack_use_markdown = true;
    const sns_message_raw = sns_event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
    const sns_message_date_epoc = new Date(sns_message_raw.StateChangeTime).getTime();

    slack_message_text = `
*Alert:* One or more errors were report by ${sns_message_raw.AlarmName}
*Date:* <!date^${sns_message_date_epoc}^{date_num} at {time_secs}^|${sns_message_raw.StateChangeTime}>
*Region:* ${sns_message_raw.Region}
*Queue:* ${sns_message_raw.Trigger.Dimensions[0].value}
`
// "*bold* `code` _italic_ ~strike~"

    slack_message = {
        text: slack_message_text,
        username: slack_message_user,
        mrkdwn: slack_use_markdown,
    }

    return JSON.stringify(slack_message);
}
```

The message in slack appears as follows:

[image]

The  variable isn't rendering. I just see the statement I'm passing to the slack API. I expect to see the supplied date formatted to the user's local time zone.

*UPDATE:* There was a good comment noticing the carrot before the pipe in the  declaration. I removed it. I'm still getting the problem, but that line in the code now looks like the following:

```
*Date:* <!date^${sns_message_date_epoc}^{date_num} at {time_secs}^|${sns_message_raw.StateChangeTime}>
```

Comment: Na, that's not it. `{date_num}` and `{time_secs}` aren't JavaScript variables I'm interpolating in the template string. They're SlackAPI tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify a `optional_link` you have to remove the last `^` delimiter, i.e. the `^` right before the `|`. Their documentation doesn't seem to specify this but I can reproduce the problem in the [Message Builder](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22%3C!date%5E1554494779%5E%7Bdate_num%7D%7CAlt%3E%20-%20%3C!date%5E1554494779%5E%7Bdate_num%7D%5E%7CAlt%3E%22%7D).

Edit: And Slack expects a epoch in seconds while `getTime()` returns a epoch in milliseconds.

Comment: Good eyes!  I see the carrot. I deleted it. I still have the issue. Although I still have the issue, that was a good catch.

Comment: @Adam When I use your original output and remove the carot I get the correct output: https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22%3C!date%5E1554494779%5E%7Bdate_num%7D%20at%20%7Btime_secs%7D%7C2019-04-05T20%3A06%3A19.749%2B0000%3E%22%7D

Comment: Bruuuuh!!! It's (a) the issue you noted and (b) I calculated the epoch incorrectly. I noticed the value you supplied in the message builder was way off from what my function was generating. I made this change `Math.floor(new Date(sns_message_raw.StateChangeTime).getTime() / 1000);` Update your answer to note that and I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Comment: `I noticed the value you supplied in the message builder was way off from what my function was generating.` Added a note. Not sure why your screenshot shows the correct values though.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Maybe I copied in the wrong code to screen shot combo? It’s been a long morning :-)